# Adding elements to a vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, mergesort

I need to sort 2 vectors (A and B) using mergesort and put the sorted elements into a 3rd vector (R).
On a test with 3 elements in A (1,3,5) and B being (2,4,6) my code runs OK until I have to insert the 4th element. At this point my code crashes with a vector subscript out of range error.

This is my first time using vectors but I thought the `push_back()` function resizes the vector. My hunch is that the target vector (R) can only hold 3 elements so when I go to insert the 4th element, my code crashes. Do I need to do something to resize R?

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


// combine two sorted lists A and B into R
// displays comparison every time it is done
void combine(vector<int> A, vector<int> B, vector<int>& R)
{
    int ia = 1;
    int ib = 1;
    int ir = 1;

    while (!A.empty() && !B.empty()) {
        if (A[ia] < B[ib]) {
            R.push_back(A[ia]);
            ia++;
            ir++;
        }
        else {
            R.push_back(B[ib]);
            ib++;
            ir++;
        }
    }
        if (!A.empty()) {
            for (int i = ia; i < A.size(); i++) {
                R.push_back(A[i]);
            }
        }
        else if (!B.empty()) {
            for (int i = ib; i < B.size(); i++) {
                R.push_back(B[i]);
            }
        }
        cout << "comparison" << endl;
        // be careful -- R comes in as an empty vector


}


int main()
{
    vector<int> L1;
    vector<int> L2;
    vector<int> L3;
    int N;  // how many elements in each of L1 and L2
    int e;  // for each element

    cout << "How many elements in each list?" << endl;
    cin >> N;

    cout << "List1" << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        cout << "element :"; cin >> e; L1.push_back(e);
    }

    cout << "List2" << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        cout << "element :"; cin >> e; L2.push_back(e);
    }


    combine(L1, L2, L3);


    cout << "The result is: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < N * 2; i++)
    {
        cout << L3[i];
    } cout << endl;

}// end of main
```

Comment: Study the condition to your `while` loop in `combine`.  Is there anything within the loop that will change the value of that condition?

Comment: I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of the `combine` function. Especially on that first loop. Think about when `A` or `B` will ever become empty.

Comment: And remember that vector indexes are zero-based.

Comment: Lastly, are you *sure* that `L3.size() == N * 2`? Why not use `L3.size()` which is guaranteed to be the exact size of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

vector A and B always not empty, unless pop_front

simply as likes,

```
if(A.at(0) < B.at(0)) {
    C.push_back(A.at(0));
    A.pop_front();
}
```

or, loop until size of A and B

```
int ia = 0;
int ib = 0;
while(ia < A.size() && ib < B.size())
{
    if(A.at(ia) < B.at(ib))
    {
        C.push_back(A.at(ia));
        ia++;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct at point: *I thought the `push_back()` function resizes the vector.*

**The error is due to invalid index access in your program.**

In your program, your terminating condition for `while` loop is `while (!A.empty() && !B.empty())`. Since you are not removing any element for vector `A` or `B` so terminating condition will never satisfy. Which leads to an infinite loop and which further leads to access of invalid index in either vector `A` or `B` (Depending upon, out of `ia` or `ib`, which have crossed actual size of respective vector).

Also note followings:

- You have started accessing elements from index 1 and not 0. Indices of vectors start from 0.
- That conditions `if (!A.empty())` and `if (!B.empty())` will be always `true`. Since you are not removing elements from vector `A` and `B`.

Following is corrected code. You can [see it working here](https://ideone.com/3UNob2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// combine two sorted lists A and B into R
// displays comparison every time it is done
void combine(vector<int> A, vector<int> B, vector<int>& R)
{
    int ia = 0;
    int ib = 0;
    int sA = A.size();
    int sB = B.size();

    while ((ia < sA) && (ib < sB)) {
        if (A[ia] < B[ib]) {
            R.push_back(A[ia]);
            ia++;
        }
        else {
            R.push_back(B[ib]);
            ib++;
        }
    }
    while(ia < sA)
    {
        R.push_back(A[ia++]);
    }
    while(ib < sB)
    {
        R.push_back(B[ib++]);
    }
    cout << "comparison" << endl;
    // be careful -- R comes in as an empty vector
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> L1;
    vector<int> L2;
    vector<int> L3;
    int N;  // how many elements in each of L1 and L2
    int e;  // for each element

    cout << "How many elements in each list?" << endl;
    cin >> N;

    cout << "List1" << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        cout << "element :"; cin >> e; L1.push_back(e);
    }

    cout << "List2" << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        cout << "element :"; cin >> e; L2.push_back(e);
    }

    combine(L1, L2, L3);

    cout << "The result is: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < N * 2; i++)
    {
        cout << L3[i] << " | ";
    } cout << endl;
}// end of main
```

Following is corrected code with some improvements and using [`iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator). You can [see it working here](https://ideone.com/0Zj2To):

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


// combine two sorted lists A and B into R
// displays comparison every time it is done
void combine(const vector<int>& A, const vector<int>& B, vector<int>& R)
{
    auto itA = A.begin();
    auto itB = B.begin();

    while ( (itA != A.end()) && (itB != B.end()) )
    {
        if (*itA < *itB) 
        {
            R.push_back(*itA);
            itA++;
        }
        else 
        {
            R.push_back(*itB);
            itB++;
        }
    }
    while(itA != A.end())
    {
        R.push_back(*itA);
        itA++;
    }
    while(itB != B.end())
    {
        R.push_back(*itB);
        itB++;
    }
    cout << "comparison" << endl;
    // be careful -- R comes in as an empty vector
}


int main()
{
    vector<int> L1;
    vector<int> L2;
    vector<int> L3;
    int N;  // how many elements in each of L1 and L2
    int e;  // for each element

    cout << "How many elements in each list?" << endl;
    cin >> N;

    cout << "List1" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cout << "element :"<<endl; cin >> e; L1.push_back(e);
    }

    cout << endl << "List2" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cout << "element :"<<endl; cin >> e; L2.push_back(e);
    }

    combine(L1, L2, L3);


    cout << "The result is: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < N * 2; i++)
    {
        cout << L3[i]<<" | ";
    }

}// end of main
```

Answer (score -1):

In your loop you check if the vectors are empty, I think you should instead be checking that their counters are in range or something like that. For example if vector A is [1,2] and B is [3,4,5] after looping twice and inserting the A vector ia will now be out of bounds but you still make it to the if statement where A[ia] is compared to B[ib] I believe this is where you are going out of bounds on your vector. Also I believe vector index starts at 0, this could also be your problem.